# Fragment menu does not disappear when using MenuHost and MenuProvider

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an activity (A) and two fragments (F1, F2). F1 starts with A, and both F1 and F2 have different menus. When I move from F1 to F2, the menu of F1 disappears and the menu of F2 appears. However, when I move back from F2 to F1 (either by a `popBackStack` or a regular `beginTransaction`, the menu of F2 does not disappear and the menu of F1 is added on top of it. If I go back and forth 5 times, I now have 5 F2 menus.

The menu section of F1:

```
private val menuProvider = object : MenuProvider {
    override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_maps_activity, menu)
    }

    override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return false
    }
}
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    requireActivity().addMenuProvider(menuProvider, viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
}
```

The menu section of F2:

```
private val menuProvider = object : MenuProvider {
    override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_add_data_item_template, menu)
    }

    override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (menuItem.itemId) {
            R.id.menu_add_data_item_template -> {
                showNewDataItemDialog()
                true
            }
            else -> false
        }
    }
}
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()
    menuHost.addMenuProvider(menuProvider, viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
}
```

Transaction from F1->F2 in parent activity:

```
private fun navigateToSection(sectionTemplateId: String) {
    ...
    val targetFragment: Fragment = someFragment.newInstance()
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
        setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit, R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit)
        replace(R.id.fragment_container_activity_add_flyover, targetFragment, "newFragment")
        addToBackStack("newFragment")
        setReorderingAllowed(true)
        commit()
    }
   ...
}
```

Transaction back to F2 (F2->F1):

```
private fun popBackStack() {
    ...
    supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
}
```

I have also tried to perform the back navigation (F2->F1) by detaching the fragment manually:

```
private fun popBackStack() {
    viewModel.setActivitySubtitle("New Flyover")
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)
    supportFragmentManager.let { manager ->
        val fragment = manager.findFragmentByTag("newFragment")
        fragment?.let { childFragment ->
            manager.beginTransaction().apply {
                manager.popBackStack()
                detach(childFragment)
                commit()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to go back by creating a new instance of F1 and using `commit` with a `transaction`. Every time, the menu of F2 does not go away. While experimenting, I found out that `onStop`, `onDetach`...etc. hooks are not called.

The result is having multiple copies of the same menu every time I go to F2. This is F1 when the activity is launched:

[image: F1]

This is F2 on first F1->F2:

[image: f1->f2]

This is F1 on going back (F1->F2->F1):
[image: f1->f2->f1]

This is F2 on second run (F1->F2->F1->F2):
[image: f1->f2->f1->f2]

As you see, I get a merry bunch of the same menu item. What I need is the menu of F2 disappearing once the fragment is no longer visible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update it.

`MenuHost`(aka the `Activity`)

```
/**
 * Invalidates the {@link android.view.Menu} to ensure that what is
 * displayed matches the current internal state of the menu.
 *
 * This should be called whenever the state of the menu is changed,
 * such as items being removed or disabled based on some user event.
 */
void invalidateMenu();
```

There is also `invalidateOptionsMenu()` on the Activity itself that calls it so you don't have to re-cast it.

So...

```
requireActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu()
```

or

```
(requireActivity() as MenuHost).invalidateMenu()
```